# Enabling CORS filter in Tomcat 7

Tags: geoserver, wms, apache, tomcat, cors

I am trying to access a WMS layer from GeoServer installed locally and adding to my Cesium JavaScript application. WMS layer was not being added. I just found from search that it may be due to CORS filter not configured. So I did configuring CORS in /etc/tomcat7/web.xml as below:

[image]

Even after configuring, I can't access the WMS from GeoServer. My responses from GeoServer in developer tools is attached as a snapshot.

[image]

Did I go wrong somewhere?

Comment: Please always include code as formatted text rather than as a picture.

Comment: You don't need CORS for WMS images to work

Answer (score 1):

My assumption are you are using jetty geoserver (installer) and you have your application on tomcat7 which is accessing WMS. In this situation a better solution is to deploy the geoserver war file in tomcat7 . This solves the root problem you won't need CORS at all !

Update :

the problem seems to be in url format check this for more reference http://docs.geoserver.org/2.8.x/en/user/services/wms/reference.html

Comment: Geoserver is already on the server.

Comment: If the application server and geoserver on same server then you don't need CORS.

Comment: Well. Alright..